# Numeric data type with "0" digits after dot

Tags: r, numeric

Today I had a look at the `pop` dataset of the `wpp2019` package and noticed that the population numbers are shown as numeric values with a "." after the last three digits (e.g. 10500 is 10.500).

```
library(wpp2019)
data("pop")
pop$`2020`
```

To remove the dots, I would usually simply turn the column into a character column and then use for example `stringr::str_replace()`, but as soon as I apply any function (except printing) to the population number columns, the dots disappear.

How can it be that this dataset shows e.g. 10.500 when printing the data.frame even though R usually removes the 0 digits after the dot for numeric values? And what would be the best way to remove the dots in the above example without losing the 0 digits?

Expected output

```
 # instead of 
pop$`2020`[153]
#[1] 164.1
# this value should return 164100 because printing the data frame 
# shows 164.100
```

Comment: without losing the zeroes after the `.`

Comment: what about ``pop$`2020` * 1000``?

Comment: that would indeed be the easiest solution here for the example column at hand. The only issue that would probably arise then is for population values below 1000 (assuming that 500 is not shown as 0.500)

Comment: there are no numbers smaller than 1000 in the data frame, and even if there was multiplying by 1000 would always work. (I think 500 would be shown as 0.500 based on the documentation I have read, except there is no value that low in the database)

Answer (score 1):

Population estimates in `wpp2019` are given in thousands.  So multiply by 1000 to get back to the estimated number of individuals:

```
> pop$`2020`[153]*1000
[1] 164100
```

R prints the decimal part sometimes but not other times based on the `digits` argument in `print`, and what else is in the vector it is printing.  For example:

```
> print(1234567.890)
[1] 1234568 # max 7 digits printed by default

> print(c(1234567.890,0.011))
[1] 1234567.890       0.011 # but when printed alongside 0.011 all the digits shown.
```

This explains why your data frame always shows all the digits but you don't see all the digits when you extract individual numbers.